# Ошибка в условии запроса: ORA-01427: подзапрос одиночной строки возвращает более одной строки

Tags: sql, oracle

Таблица состоит из колонок: `(note, note_owner)`.
Есть таблица работников с колонками: `(empoyer_name, his_manager_name)`.

Необходимо прочитать из первой таблицы записи, которые принадлежат определённому менеджеру или его работникам.

Попытался вот так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fgac_table 
WHERE note_owner = 'manager_1' 
OR note_owner = (
    SELECT empoyer_name 
    FROM employers_table 
    WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1');
```

Но ошибка:

> ORA-01427: подзапрос одиночной строки возвращает более одной строки

Как нужно исправить запрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение `IN` помогает в вашем случае.

**SQL**

```
SELECT* FROM fgac_table WHERE
    note_owner = 'manager_1' 
    OR note_owner IN (SELECT empoyer_name FROM employers_table WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1');
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот так по условию `EXISTS` с корреляционным подзапросом:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fgac_table 
WHERE note_owner = 'manager_1' 
OR EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 
     FROM employers_table 
     WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1' AND empoyer_name = note_owner);
```

Если с оператором `IN`, то лучше перенести условие `OR` в подзапрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM fgac_table 
WHERE note_owner IN (
    SELECT name
    FROM (
        SELECT empoyer_name name
        FROM employers_table 
        WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'manager_1' name FROM dual));
```

---

PS Возможные ошибки в дизайне таблиц:

- связь по `note_owner` и `empoyer_name` не уникальна, могут быть тёзки однофамильцы, надо создать уникальный идентификатор записей
- принято давать имена соответствующие тому, что они описывают: таблица работников должна называться *employeеs*, а то сейчас это - работодатели